# Get child work items for a specific parent in TFS

Tags: tfs

How to get child work items for a specific parent in TFS? I need a Flat List which takes a parent ID as a query parameter and returns the child work items.

Note: Till now I'm able to to do this only with the 'Work Items and Direct Links' query.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot achieve that by "Flat list of work items" query as there ins't the fields/condition to query that, we can use "Tree of work items":

1. Select "**Tree of work items**"
2. Set up the query for the top level work items, 
   "**User Story**" with id `105` for example here (See below screenshot, just specify the **Parent** work item **ID** here).
3. Under "**Filters for linked work items**" you can exclude descendent
   items, or specify the **Child** work item types, for example only
   show **Task** and **Bug**, just set `Work Item Type in Task,Bug`, or
   leave it as **[Any]**, it will returns all the types of child work
   items for the specific Parent.
4. Filter options : **Match top-level work items first**, Type of tree :
   **Parent/Child**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I need a query which gives a flat list (this is a requirement as I am planning to use this query as an input to TFS dashboard widget ("Code Tile") which expect a flat query only.

Comment: @gsbellu Unfortunately, we can not achieve that via flat list, there is no the condition/fields for the query.

Answer (score -1):

You can custom widget to get work items by using [WorkItemTrackingHttpClient](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2) (e.g. queryById()), then display the result what you want.

About custom dashboard widget: [Add a dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget).

There are many extension samples that can help you: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)