# TFS - Display Child Entities without Parent

Tags: tfs

Trying to create a TFS query which displays a list of children PBIs of a Feature without displaying the feature. The Feature and PBIs are linked through child-parent relationship.

Any idea if this is possible?

Josh

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot only display the children workitems with flat for the Parent/Child linked work items.

We can only query both Parent and Child workitems with the query type `Work items and direct links` or `Tree of work items`.

However you can create a `Work items and direct links` or `Tree of work items` query with both Parent and Child workitems, then [open the query in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel) then filter out the Child workitems. Or trying list the children workitems with TFS API.

Reference this similar thread : [Get child work items for a specific parent in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236238/get-child-work-items-for-a-specific-parent-in-tfs/)

Comment: is there a User Voice entry tracking this ask? I've got VSO dashboards with queries for "Remaining Items" and it gives an inaccurate count of +1 because it's inclusive of the Parent. You're also unable to do charts on non-flat queries.